# I am able to send single SMs using my C# code as follows. Its using contacts And data from Gridview

Tags: c#, sql

Using this code I am able to send single SMS only.When Gridview is having only one row code is sending SMS but when Gridview is having more than one row code is not sending SMS.

When I am providing a fixed string like 'Hi' or 'Hellow' its sending SMS to multiple recipients.I am not experienced coder so I am not having idea why this is happening.

```
protected void btnallocate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int n = 0;
    int studentchecked = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdallocatestudent.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkallocate = (CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkallocate");
        if (chkallocate.Checked)
        {
            ds = new DataSet();
            Label lblstudentid = (Label)row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblstudentid");
            Label lblname = (Label)row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblname");
            Label lblprimarymob = (Label)row.Cells[6].FindControl("lblprimarymob");
            Label lblsecondarymob = (Label)row.Cells[7].FindControl("lblsecondarymob");
            Label lblcoursename = (Label)row.Cells[9].FindControl("lblcoursename");
            Label lblbatchdate = (Label)row.Cells[12].FindControl("lblbatchdate");
            Label lbltimefrom = (Label)row.Cells[13].FindControl("lbltimefrom");
            Label lbltimeto = (Label)row.Cells[14].FindControl("lbltimeto");
            int batchid = Convert.ToInt32(drlbatch.SelectedValue);
            string batchname = drlbatch.SelectedItem.Text;
            int studentid = Convert.ToInt32(lblstudentid.Text);
            string primarymob = lblprimarymob.Text;
            string secondarymob = lblsecondarymob.Text;
            string name = lblname.Text;
            string coursename = lblcoursename.Text;
            //getbatchinfo(batchid);
            int courseid = Convert.ToInt32(drlcourse.SelectedValue);
            int franchiseeid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Franchisee"]);
            string batchdate = lblbatchdate.Text;
            string timefrom = lbltimefrom.Text;
            string timeto = lbltimeto.Text;
            //string timefrom = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][4]);
            //string timeto = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][5]);
            string message = "Dear " + name + ", Your batch " + batchname + " will be on " + batchdate + " from " + timefrom + " " + timeto + " for course " + coursename;
            studentchecked = studentchecked + 1;
            //string message = "Hi!!!";
            n = b.insertbatchallocation(batchid, studentid, courseid, batchdate, franchiseeid, message);
            SendSMS1(message, primarymob);
            SendSMS1(message, secondarymob);
        }
    }
    drlcourse.ClearSelection();
    drlbatch.ClearSelection();
    getstudentsforallocation(Convert.ToInt32(drlcourse.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(drlbatch.SelectedValue));
    if (studentchecked > 0 && n > 0)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Students batch allocation successfull');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Check at least one Checkbox for allocating students to batch');", true);
    }
}

public void SendSMS1(string message, string contact)
{

    //HTTP connection
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://fast.admarksolution.com/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=kiran&password=abc123&msisdn=91" + contact + "&sid=PRERNA&msg=" + message + "&fl=0&gwid=2");
    //Get response from Ozeki NG SMS Gateway Server and read the answer
    HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
    System.IO.StreamReader respStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream());
    string responseString = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    respStreamReader.Close();
    myResp.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Take a delegate process action to send SMS**

```
private delegate void sendSmsDelegate();
```

**Take DataTable before foreach loop:**

```
DataTable dtSMS= new DataTable();
dtSMS.Columns.Add("message", typeof(string));
dtSMS.Columns.Add("mobileNo", typeof(string));
```

**inside foreach loop**

```
dtSMS.Rows.Add(mobileNo, primarymob);
dtSMS.Rows.Add(message, secondarymob);
```

**After foreach loop create and invoke delegate**

```
ViewState["dtTemp"]=dtSMS;
sendSmsDelegate sendAlert = new sendSmsDelegate(sendSmsAsync);
sendAlert.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

**define function to send SMS**

```
private void sendSmsAsync()
{
    DataTable dtSms = ViewState["dtTemp"] as DataTable;
    if (dtSms.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtSms.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           // lines of code to send sms from your SendSMS1()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried all ways suggested by you guys which couldn't resolve the issue.
 Issue was not with code it was related to database.I had inserted a value of course name as 'c#' for testing my code.I entered another value of course name as 'MCA' and tried with more than one rows in gridview it worked.But it didn't work for Course Name c#.when I removed # in 'c#' from table in database it worked.
 Course name is at the end of SMS expected to be sent, can somebody explain how # was preventing code from working.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can using special characters passed in parameters cause this situation?

Comment: Can using special characters passed in parameters cause this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It may be problem in your Grid view data 
if your getting any run time error please post.

mainly don't Post original API link any ware it my use some other person.

Code everything ok That's why it working when put Message manually

Comment: I tried all ways suggested by you guys which couldn't resolve the issue.
 Issue was not with code it was related to database.I had inserted a value of course name as 'c#' for testing my code.I entered another value of course name as 'MCA' and tried with more than one rows in gridview it worked.But it didn't work for Course Name c#.when I removed # in 'c#' from table in database it worked.
 Course name is at the end of SMS expected to be sent, can somebody explain how # was preventing code from working.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I tried all ways suggested by you guys which couldn't resolve the issue.
 Issue was not with code it was related to database.I had inserted a value of course name as 'c#' for testing my code.I entered another value of course name as 'MCA' and tried with more than one rows in gridview it worked.But it didn't work for Course Name c#.when I removed # in 'c#' from table in database it worked.
 Course name is at the end of SMS expected to be sent, can somebody explain how # was preventing code from working.
Thanks in advance!!